# Django pytest error - Invalid pk because user object (created with bakery) not found

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, pytest

I'm using DjangoRestFramework 3.13 and pytest 7.1.
My API tests are currently failing due to errors on missing object when passing its primary key to serializer.

I have the following fixture for creating API client with authenticated user

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def user_account(db):
    def _user(**kwargs):
        return baker.make("accounts.UserAccount", **kwargs)
    return _user

@pytest.fixture()
def api_client(user_account):
    def _api_client(auth_user=None):
        if auth_user is None:
            auth_user = user_account()
        client = _CustomAPIClient()
        client.force_authenticate(auth_user)
        return client
    return _api_client
```

The testing method looks like this:

```py
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_create_customobject_api_success(api_client, data):
    
    client = api_client()
    url = reverse("api-custom:list")
    response = client.post(url, data)

    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED
    assert response.data["status"] == "PENDING"
    assert response.data["task_id"] != ""
```

Now, when I test this previous route that creates CustomObject associated to that user, I get the following error:

```
rest_framework.exceptions.ValidationError: {'user': [ErrorDetail(string='Invalid pk "13c6e59c-51ba-44e0-b9b6-07501c636330" - object does not exist.', code='does_not_exist')]}
```

This error occurs when my Celery task finishes and is about to create my CustomObject :

```py
serializer = CustomSerializer(data=custom_data)

if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
    return serializer.data
else:
     logging.error("Custom serializer invalid: %s", serializer.errors)
     raise serializers.ValidationError(serializer.errors)
```

The asynchronous task is being called from a Django view post method, and the `custom_data` has `user` property with user UUID : `custom_data["user"] = request.user.uuid`

I checked if my `api_client` actually creates a valid user, and it does.

Everything works fine outside of pytest. Any ideas why the user doesn't exist anymore in database when the serializer vaidation method is called ?
Has it anything to do with doing asynchronous task ? Is there any chances the database is being flushed before the task finishes ?

Comment: i think you have to include [User fixture in your test case].

Comment: Can you elaborate on that ? I only need the `api_client` fixture to write my test, and it does make a call to the `user_account` fixture. So why should I include an additional reference to the `user_account` fixture, and to do what ? I don't see where it will be referenced in my test case

Comment: does your api is using authenticated class or allowany class? if you are using allowany then its not compulsory if yes then you have to use it.

Comment: It is using `JWTAuthentication` class from drf_simplejwt indeed. But where should I call the reference to the fixture in the test ? The user is actually created, but it doesn't exist anymore in the db by the time the serializer is called with the reference to the user.

Comment: can i show you mine example, how i m doing?

Comment: I guess you can post an answer with an example of yours, sure. It may help other people here on SO to understand how one should operate in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

This is my **view.py** file that contain only two method **POST** and **GET**.

```
class SongViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    with transaction.atomic():
        queryset = Song.objects.all()
        serializer_class = SongSerializer
        http_method_names = ['post', 'get']
        permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

I m creating **confest.py** file that contain some **fixture** that i m using in my test cases.
Here i m creating superuser. you can create simple user that can request.

```
fake = Faker()

@pytest.fixture
def create_user():
    user = User.objects.create_superuser(username='admin', email='admin@gmail.com', password='admin')
    return user

@pytest.fixture
def create_10_fake_songs():
    songs = []
    for _ in range(10):
        sng = Song.objects.create(
            title=fake.word(),
            artist=fake.name(),
            lyrics=fake.paragraph(),
            file_location=fake.file_path())
        songs.append(sng)
    return songs
```

In test_api.py Here i m using those fixture.

```
import pytest
from rest_framework.test import APIClient
from manualapp.models import Song
from testutils.confest import create_10_fake_songs, create_user
client = APIClient()

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_create_song(create_user):
    data = {
        "title": "Wo lamhy wo batin",
        "artist": "sasta atif aslam",
        "lyrics": "unknown",
        "file_location": "example_slug_123",
        "user_time": "16:00:00"
    }
    client.force_authenticate(user=create_user)
    url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/song/'   
    response = client.post(url, data=data, format='json')
    assert response.status_code == 201
    last_obj = Song.objects.last()
    assert last_obj.title == response.json()['title']
```

Comment: OK so you call `force_authenticate()` method of APIClient with the user as parameter inside the test function. Can you explain how it is different to authenticating the client directly within the fixture definition as I'm doing in my example and why we should expect different behaviours ?

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/
please read it from here.

Comment: Sorry, but I already read the DRF doc on testing and it doesn't look to provide hints on why we should force_authenticate within the test method (actually it doesn't even mention pytest). Also it doesn't explain why fixture objects seem to be flushed (which is my original question)